# Simple procedure-Error in .local(x, ...) : Raster Layer has no NA cells for which to compute a distance

Tags: distance, r-raster

I am working in Simple procedure in R.I have face the problem when i have started  to calculate the Energy balance and R has sent me the message:  Error in .local(x, ...) :   Raster Layer has no NA cells for which to compute a distance. Can you help me and give me some tips to overcome the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example in order to receive help

Comment: What did you try? Did you look at the documentation ( `?raster::distance` )?

Comment: hello, I have tried to calculate the energy balance, the R  has sent me the message: Error in .local(x, ...): Raster Layer has no NA cells for which to compute a distance. On the other hand, the weather station is near to my study, it has to inside the study area or not.
thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You can edit your question to show what you tried. And to show that you read the documentation which seems to be very clear about the issue you are having. Please include a  minimal example (like in the R help files) to illustrate what you want to do and allowing others to help you.